# How to make image dimensions shrink according to container?

Tags: html, css

I have this blogspot blog: [sourcewing.blogspot.com](http://sourcewing.blogspot.com)

Now if you go to **drawings** tab, you'll notice the **electric bulb** image is not aligned center of the post. What I want to say is that it is taking its original width and height. If the width would be 1200px, it would go out of the **tbody** (Please check the HTML of this image).

What I want is that it should shrink automatically (maintaining the proportions), according to the width of **div class="post-body entry-content"...** element (you'd find by inspect element). This should apply on the **all images** that have more width than this **div**.

Also, I would like to know why isn't it automatically shrinking, while the text is automatically aligned?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `max-width` css rule.

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data critical for the understanding of your question. Please remember to provide all necessary data (code, configuration data, exception name ...) in **the question itself**. If the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are missing a few things.

```
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This will achieve exactly what you are after.

Just to explain:

`height: auto;` - This will make sure your picture remains in proportion.

`max-width: 100%;` - Your image will behave responsively but wont break it's own natural sizing.

`box-sizing: border-box;` - Because you have padding you don't want to break the width this will keep padding but not break out of your container.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fixed `height` and `width` attributes from the `img` element.

You can then add a class eg `.auto-contain` or whatever with the following css:

```
.auto-contain {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will force the image to always have the same width as the container, but the height will grow in proportion.

Comment: I want to maintain the image proportions.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'll try and tell.

Comment: Remove the `width: 100%`-rule then...

Comment: Please check my question detail. I forgot to mention the div which should contain the image and NOT allow the image to go out of it.

Comment: Your image is a child of the table. Remove the whole table, set the image as a direct child of the parent class you mentioned. The whole table is pretty unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

First remove the width and height attribute from your `img` tag.

To solve the problem :

```
img {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

if you set height and width 100% normally your image would be as big as the parent. But in your case this does not work. 90% however looks better.

Comment: Please check my question detail. I forgot to mention the div which should contain the image and NOT allow the image to go out of it.

Comment: I want it to be as big as div with class="post-body entry-content". It is the image's parent, NO? When we set the width and height 100%, why doesn't it stay inside this parent?